# ¿Es posible usar telnet para acceder a un sitio por HTTPS?

Tags: telnet

Intento conectarme a https://es.stackoverflow.com/ usando Telnet,

```
telnet https://es.stackoverflow.com/ 443
```

Obtengo como respuesta

```
telnet: could not resolve https://es.stackoverflow.com/443: Name or service not known
```

Si intento de esta manera

```
telnet es.stackoverflow.com 443
```

Puedo conectarme pero al intentar construir la petición, el servidor cierra la conexión antes

```
Trying 151.101.1.69...
Connected to es.stackoverflow.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET / HTTP/1.1
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

1. ¿Estoy haciendo algo incorrecto o simplemente no es posible hacerlo?
2. De no ser posible, ¿existe alguna otra herramienta que me permita intentar conectarme usando consola?. Uso Debian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para sitios con HTTPS debes usar `openssl`, `telnet` es colo compatible con HTTP

```
openssl s_client -connect https://es.stackoverflow.com/:443
```

> Con `telnet`, el servidor web espera pacientemente a que escribas la
>   solicitud por completo. `s_client` **NO**. 
>   Así que escribe la solicitud en un editor de texto y téngala lista
>   para pegar justo después de que los detalles del certificado SSL se
>   desplacen.

Eh leido que usas Debian, pero por las dudas en Ubuntu debes utilizar:

```
gnutls https://es.stackoverflow.com/:443
```